setTimeout to close modal and redirect to url
I opened the modal 2 minutes before the expiry time. I want that after these 2 minutes the modal will close again and redirect to a url. how to do it? Any help would be much appreciated.
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {           
    var expiryTime      = `{{ request.session.get_expiry_age }}`;
    var openModalTime   = (expiryTime - 120) * 1000; 
    // This part is working fine:
    ------------------------------------
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#sessionTimeoutModal').modal('show');
    }, openModalTime);  
    //----------------------------------
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#sessionTimeoutModal').modal('hide');
        window.location.href = "{% url 'login' %}";
    }, (openModalTime + 121) * 1000);
});


I guess it is openModalTime + 240. Because 121 is just at 0.

I changed it to 240 but it's not working.

Plus add please setTimeout(function() {         $('#sessionTimeoutModal').modal('show');         redirect_to_login();     }, (openModalTime + 120)*1000); What is working?

It's still not working

Let us go step by step. The .modal('show') part is working fine? Just the .modal('hide') part does not work? You took the login function out. Why do you need a setTimeout for the show part?

In fact, I opened the modal just before it expired. After exactly that amount of time I want to redirect here window.location.href = "{% url 'login' %}". That's all.

That is a bit tricky. Because you get the expiry time in unixtime, right? Can you do a console.log(openModalTime)? That should be a huge number.

console output: 180000

2 minutes should be 120000.



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Session Timeout Modal Example</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Session Timeout Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="sessionTimeoutModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="sessionTimeoutModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="sessionTimeoutModalLabel">Session Timeout</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          Your session is about to expire.
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      var expiryTime = 3; // Hardcoded expiry time for demonstration (5 minutes)
      var openModalTime = (expiryTime - 120) * 1000; // Time to open modal before expiry (2 minutes before expiry)

      // Show the modal at the specified 'openModalTime'
      setTimeout(function() {
        var modalElement = document.getElementById('sessionTimeoutModal');
        var sessionTimeoutModal = new bootstrap.Modal(modalElement);
        sessionTimeoutModal.show();
      }, openModalTime);

      // Hide the modal and redirect at 'expiryTime'
      setTimeout(function() {
        var modalElement = document.getElementById('sessionTimeoutModal');
        var sessionTimeoutModal = new bootstrap.Modal(modalElement);
        sessionTimeoutModal.hide();
        window.location.href = "login.html"; // Redirect to a hardcoded login page
      }, expiryTime * 1000);
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>



Here I have Created a small example. I have Hard coded the values please change them to variables.
